# How can I show the template only when creating new record in form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I do have the template content in `communities/template.html.erb`
I'd like to show that only when the user is creating new community.
How can I do that? shouldn't it be something like this?

```
<% if @community.new_record? %>  
    <textarea class="text_area"><%= render file: "communities/template" %></textarea>
<% else %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, :class => 'text_area' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `file:` by the looks of it. [`file:`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) is for specifying files that are outside of your Rails app. Also, do you intend to render it within a `textarea`?

And for future questions it's always handy to tell us what the error is rather than making us guess.

Comment: Yes I'd like to render it within a textarea because it's template purpose.

Comment: Ok then, try it without `file:` like I said.

Comment: I don't think it's the point. Because this is working on the other part except it's read-only. here even if I code html form tag directly, I'm still missing what column this is for. That's the problem part.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Update your question with your error message or a description of what isn't working.

Comment: What is the larger context of that snippet? Is it in a form that gets submitted? Do have some ajax-y stuff going on that we can't see?